# Include file with no extension in my ant build for my war file

Tags: java, ant, war

When I build my .war file via ant, it is excluding a file that doesn't have an extension from the class path.  So in the class path there are two specific files WEB-INF/classes/fruit/apple.ppk and then WEB-INF/classes/fruit/apple_dsa, my ant builds the .ppk into the war, but excludes the file with no extension for some reason, how can I avoid this?  Here is my ant build for the war file

```
<target name="create-war"
        depends="initialize, compile, create-manifest"
        description="Creates an WAR file">

    <war destfile="${dist.dir}/${war.name}"
         webxml="${web.root}/WEB-INF/web.xml"
         manifest="${build.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
         duplicate="fail">
        <classes dir="${java.classes.dir}">
            <exclude name="**/*test*" />
        </classes>
        <fileset dir="${web.root}">
            <exclude name="**/*test*" />
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/classes/**" />
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml" />
            <exclude name="**/context.xml" />
        </fileset>
    </war>

</target>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an awnser, it was a lot easier than I though:

http://bobcat.webappcabaret.net/javachina/faq/ant_01.htm#ant_mid_Q080

If files are in the directory:

```
<include name="a,b,c"/>
```

If files are in the directory or subdirectories:

```
<include name="**/a,**/b,**/c"/>
```

If you want all files without extension are in the directory or subdirectories:

```
<exclude name="**/*.*"/>
```

Comment: Link is broken now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding

```
<include name ="*"/> 
<exclude name="*.*"/>
```

Comment: ok, now try with that and additionally <exclude name="*.*"/> ... see edited answer, this isn't displaying right

Comment: That gets rid of all the files with extensions in my ant build.  And an FYI i am putting these in the <classes></classes> tags.

Comment: I think this needs to go in the fileset element

Comment: Ok, put it in the fileset element, and both/all have no effect on the output of the fruit directory.